# Wordpress Ajax not calling the js at all within widget

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I am trying to run AJAX through wordpress on my widget; using the following:

dawn-tab-widget.php: (my main widget's file)

```
class dawn_tab_widget { 
    ... // referring to irrelevant functions in the class

    function tab_ajax_result() { 
        echo 'helloworld';
        die();
    }     
}
wp_enqueue_script( 'tab-ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/tab-ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_localize_script( 'tab-ajax', 'ajaxObject', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); 
add_action('wp_ajax_tab_ajax', 'tab_ajax_result');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tab', 'tab_ajax_result');
```

tab-ajax.js (in /template/assets/js/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert("Loading Page");
    var data = { action: 'tab_ajax_script' },
    $.post(ajaxObject.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        if(response.length > 2) {
            alert("loaded");
        }
    });
})
```

It simply does not work, I don't even get my "Loading" alert. Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

this `add_action('wp_ajax_tab_ajax', 'tab_ajax_result');` will not work cause function `tab_ajax_result` is inside the class. please read more about [adding action when functions are inside a class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Using_with_a_Class).